# How to have uniform distribution drop to zero at edges?

Tags: julia

```
using Plots
using Distributions
gr()

plot(Uniform(0,1))
xlabel!("velocity")
ylabel!("probability density")
xlims!(-0.5, 1.5)
ylims!(0, 1.5)
```

I am trying to plot a uniform distribution with area under the curve = 1. I would like the edges of the curve to drop to zero so the curve looks more like a box and less like a straight line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to explicitly plot the actual `pdf` of the distribution over some relevant range of `x` values. For example:

```
using Plots, Distributions

x = -0.5:0.001:1.5
plot(x, pdf.(Uniform(0,1), x), label="distribution")
xlabel!("velocity")
ylabel!("probability density")
xlims!(-0.5, 1.5)
ylims!(0, 1.5)
```

yields

[image: uniform pdf from 0 to 1]

Comment: Sorry, what is a pdf here? Is there documentation for it?

Comment: pdf = probability density function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function, or for the specific function  I'm using here try `? pdf` at the Julia REPL with Distributions loaded